# How to specify format culture in a XAML converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cultureinfo

When we use static double values in XAML, how can we specify in which format they are provided?

Example:

```
<Rectangle>
  <Rectangle.Opacity>
    <Binding Path="IsDimmed" Converter="{StaticResource boolToDoubleConverter}" ConverterParameter="0.8"/>
  </Rectangle.Opacity>
</Rectangle>
```

with the converter method

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
   return double.Parse((string)parameter, culture);
}
```

The problem is that on a machine, where decimals are separated by `,`, the conversion method fails or returns a wrong value, respectively.

I do not want to set the InvariantCulture in the `Parse()` method, because the converter might in some place be used to parse user input, which is why the `culture` parameter should still be applied.

If I specify the value as a resource with `<sys:Double x:Key="dimValue">0.8</sys:Double>`, the converter parameter becomes a double type but before being parsed is cast to a string.

So I would like to specify somehow, that the value is indicated in en-GB format like `ConverterParameter="0.8" ConverterParameterCulture="en-GB"/>`.

Is this possible somehow without the need to create a puffy MultiValueConverter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`ConverterCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `Binding` for this purpose :

```
<Binding Path="IsDimmed" Converter="{StaticResource boolToDoubleConverter}" 
         ConverterParameter="0.8" ConverterCulture="en-GB"/>
```

Comment: Man I was close with my guess... 8-)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes I use:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Margin="3" Text="{Binding [Value], Mode=OneTime, StringFormat={}{0:N2}, ConverterCulture={x:Static glob:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

Where `glob` is:

```
xmlns:glob="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
```